# Clock issue with Motorola Razr HD Maxx (stock 4.4.2 firmware)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, clock, motorola-droid-razr, date-and-time

I have a Verizon Motorola Razr HD Maxx, running the latest firmware (182.46.15.XT926). My phone was dropped and the screen shattered about 6 months ago. The Razr was powered off and left alone while I switched to an older phone until I could find the time and money to get a screen replacement. Having just done so, my phone is now in mostly working order. I can browse on 4G and make/receive test messages and calls.

However, the date/time on the phone are completely inaccurate. It is currently reporting the date as 3/15/2015, and the time as 6:52 as of the time of this post (while it is 10:56 AM EST, 5/21/2015 in reality). Manually attempting to change the time does not work - After modifying the time and selecting done, the change does not persist.

I do not appear to be the only one with this problem - others have reported it online (see [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-4-kitkat/394439-razr-hd-time-date-won-t-update-can-t-connect-google.html) and [here](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/2b9452ac6b) for example), but no solutions have been posted which worked. I am curious if anyone here has input as to a solution.

This is a huge impediment for me, since many apps rely on the time and any SSL cert checking will fail due to the incorrect date, preventing access to Google Play.

Comment: What time settings have you tried? Have you set it to manual, or let it auto-update from network? Is the device rooted?

Comment: The devices is not rooted - totally stock firmware, just with apps installed via google play (nothing sideloaded). I have tried setting the time to manual (changes don't stick for date or time, though timezone will stick and adjust the displayed time by the correct number of hours). Enabling 'Automatic date & time' to use network provided time does not appear to do anything. I have done so with and without the sim, rebooted in and out of safemode, and every combination thereof to try and get the phone to correctly pull time from the network.

Comment: 'Automatic time zone' correctly identifies my time zone as eastern when it is enabled (e.g. i manually set to mountain time, enable automatic time zone, and the phone switches to eastern)

Comment: OK, that limits the possibilities. I don't see how that could have been caused by the screen broke (if it wasn't there before), but that might be coincidence. A firmware update might solve it. If there is no such, [ClockSync](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync) app might help; though without root it cannot adjust "to the second". Still worth a try.

Comment: Any suggestions on getting ClockSync installed without access to google play? An inaccurate clock means I can't do anything over SSL

Comment: Check my list of [sync apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_544); for ClockSync it has a download link for the `.apk`. You might also wish to take a look at *Racoon* (find the links at the bottom of [this page](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets)), which is a PC client for Playstore.

Comment: I installed ClockSync, and running in rootless it isn't able to do anything. It navigates to the date & time settings, there's a notification at the bottom that it's going to set the time to the actual time, but when the counter hits zero nothing happens and it resets.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! I'm not used to non-rooted devices (I root new devices almost before unpacking) – and to my knowledge, the limitation was just "diff must be at least 30s". Looks like that's changed with some Android version (or with the app). Not sure whether you'll have more look with one of the others from that page (which you could download using Racoon); I'm out of ideas then, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

OK, software can't solve a hardware problem. Took the phone apart and disconnected the battery for ten minutes. Reconnected the phone and the clock reverted to when the device was manufactured (i'm guessing, was 2010). But, could now be adjusted as one would expect.